# iOS Objective C iBeacon Sorted UITable View

Tags: arrays, uitableview, sorting, ibeacon

I'm currently writing a little iBeacon application and I would like to list all the beacons as they are discovered sorted on their on their proximity, e.g. Immediate, near, far.

As they are discovered they are added to the table view based on their proximity status.

The UI table view will show the major and minor and the immediate beacons will be at the top with the far beacons being at the bottom.

I can dynamically add the beacons to the table no problem but I am having issues with sorting the data as and when the beacons are discovered.

If the Array has all the beacons in I can sort it no problem using a sort descriptor, the problem is when a beacon changes from far to near or a new beacon is turned on that is immediate, it always ends up at the bottom of the table.

I'm guessing I should probably use:

insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation

But IO'm not sure how I would do this at the minute.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-sort the array of beacons each time a beacon gets added to the visible list, and then call `[tableView reloadData]`.  Below is an example of a sorting in a method, which is designed to get called on each ranging callback.

```
- (void) updateIBeacons:(NSArray *)iBeaconsSeen {
    _firstRangingUpdateReceived = YES;
    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
    __block BOOL resortNeeded = NO;
    __block BOOL replaced = NO;
    NSMutableArray *newSortedIBeacons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[_sortedIBeacons copy]];
    [iBeaconsSeen enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLBeacon * iBeacon, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        replaced = NO;
        [_sortedIBeacons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLBeacon * existingIBeacon, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([existingIBeacon.proximityUUID isEqual:iBeacon.proximityUUID]  &&
                [existingIBeacon.major isEqual:iBeacon.major] &&
                [existingIBeacon.minor isEqual:iBeacon.minor]) {
                [newSortedIBeacons setObject:iBeacon atIndexedSubscript:idx];
                replaced = YES;
            }
        }];
        [_iBeaconLastSeenTime setObject:now forKey: iBeacon];
        if (!replaced) {
            resortNeeded = YES;
            [newSortedIBeacons addObject: iBeacon];
        }

    }];

    // now remove any iBeacons that have not been seen in the last 5 seconds
    for (long i = newSortedIBeacons.count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        NSDate * lastSeen = (NSDate *) [_iBeaconLastSeenTime objectForKey:[newSortedIBeacons objectAtIndex:i]];
        if ([now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastSeen] > 5) {
            [newSortedIBeacons removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            resortNeeded = YES;
        }
    }

    if (resortNeeded) {
        NSLog(@"We need to sort again");
        NSArray *sortedArray = [newSortedIBeacons sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(CLBeacon* obj1, CLBeacon* obj2) {
            NSString *p1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@", [obj1.proximityUUID UUIDString], obj1.major, obj1.minor];
            NSString *p2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@", [obj2.proximityUUID UUIDString], obj2.major, obj2.minor];
            return [p1 compare:p2];
        }];
        _sortedIBeacons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedArray];
    }
    else {
        _sortedIBeacons = newSortedIBeacons;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method that adds a newly discovered beacon to the tableview's datasource, you can first sort the beacons array and then do `[tableView reloadData]`